# Hibernate returns data very slow vs native query (BasicExtractor takes most time)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I am fetching data via a custom `nativeQuery` which does not take parameters. The query itself returns very fast when executed through the MYSQL Workbench. The query could be something like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tbl", nativeQuery = true)
List<dataModel> getData();
```

But Hibernate returns the data very slowly. Upon looking through the logs I can see that I get this line for most of the time it takes to return:

```
2018-03-29 10:07:41.352 TRACE 6496 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([tblCol1] : [colVal1]) - [xxx]
```

There are no relationships which need fetching, so lazy fetching should not be of any concern.

Do I understand correctly that the issue is mainly with Hibernate mapping the fetched values to my Hibernate Model?

Is there a way to speed this up significantly?

Any help is of course appreciated!

EDIT: I think bean creation is the issue here as hinted at by Paizo. I think the only way of speeding up that query is to use a native query and skip creating entities.

Comment: How many rows there is table ?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL that hibernate generates for any anomalities?

Comment: The table has around 60.000 rows and data length is around 8 Mb. I am selecting via an index and limiting Results to 200 rows. In Workbench the results return immediately while via Hibernate it takes almost a second.

Since I am using nativeQuery, the SQL command is exactly the same.

Comment: could you please check without limit on workbench ? and then check the time

Comment: paste the log please; consider that you are creating a bean instance for every row while using whatever SQL client it does not. A second to fetch is not a lot, also log level trace slow down everything

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered same issue, when loading data from 20k rows took ~7 seconds.

Disabling query logging (not using trace level) increased speed to ~300ms for same amount of rows.